# SQL reporting services reference

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, web-reference

I want to add service reference to SQL reporting services on local machine. In Reporting Service Configuration Manager under Web Service URL tab I have report service URL exposed, I have tried to add web reference to project with that Web Reference URL, but it can not be found.

Please tell me am I missing something or is this right way to to?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you're adding a reference to http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx and it isn't working? Cam you access that address in a browser?

Comment: Yes I am adding that reference and it can not find service when I try to add id as web reference. 

When I open it in browser it looks like this:

localhost/ReportServer - /


________________________________________________

________________________________________________

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.50.1600.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

http://server/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx

Comment: What should it be for the ReportService2010 endpoint (Sql 2008 R2)? Is it  `http://server/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two kind of address in SSRS, (youcan find them on SSRS Configuration Tool)

```
 //localhost:xxxx/Reports
```

and

```
 //localhost:xxxx/ReportServer
```

you have to use `ReportServer`

Comment: I do use report server and I add ReportService.asmx to URL so it looks like this https://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx is it because of ports that you specified as xxxx??

Comment: @SonOfOmer - I actuallymeans you have touse ReportService.asmx after `//localhost:xxxx/ReportServer` and `xxxx` means portnumber. So you missed port number and thatswhy youcan not connect to web service

Comment: In Reporting Service Configuration Manager TCP port is 80 and I tried to visit https://localhost:80/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx and page is not found.

Comment: Canyou open this URL `//localhost:80/ReportServer/`?

Comment: Yes and opened page contains 

"localhost/ReportServer

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.50.1600.1" text

Comment: @SonOfOmar - if you can see `//localhost:80/ReportServer/` then it is finished, just use this address not `//localhost:80/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx` both are the same, and at theen Do you use SSL?

Comment: I have been trying to figure out for an hour why my report wasn't deploying after I changed the production server. I should have checked stack as always. Would have saved me some time. I must remember "reportserver" not just report. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try this url:
http://localhost/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx?WSDL

WSDL at the end of the url is very important, because only by this querystring web-service will return the Web-Service Definition for the reporting services reference.

Other way, in "Add web-reference" dialog you can choose the "Web services on the local machine" (see the picture), and choose your service there.

[alt text http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/2387/solution.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/2387/solution.png)

Additional information about permissions needed is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169816.aspx